# download file producing .htm file instead of .mp3 once downloaded on my laravel 10 project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

Hi so I'm working with this simple project where i want to download the file that i purchased. Upon hitting the download button. I am expecting for a .mp3 file as a download but got .htm instead and when i try to click the downloaded file it just redirect me to the view page instead.

Here are the codes for my controller:

```
public function downloadSong($songId)
    {
        $song = Song::find($songId);

        if ($song) {
            $filePath = storage_path('app/public/audio/songs/' . $song->audio_file);

            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $fileName = $song->title . '.mp3';

                return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, [
                    'Content-Type' => 'audio/mpeg',
                    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"',
                ]);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Song not found.');
    }
```

Here's for the download button:

```
<a href="{{ route('download.song', $item->song->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary" download>Download Song</a>
```

Here's for the route:

```
Route::get('/orders/download/song/{song}', [OrderController::class, 'downloadSong'])->name('download.song');
```

Here's the reference why I use the $songId as argument to fetch the data from the order:

```
public function placeOrder()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $cartItems = $user->cartItems;

        if (count($cartItems) === 0) {
            return redirect()->route('cart.index')->with('error', 'Your cart is empty. Nothing to order.');
        }

        $order = Order::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'order_total' => $cartItems->sum('price'),
        ]);

        foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
            $price = 0;
            $songId = null;
            $albumId = null;

            if ($cartItem->product_type === 'song' && $cartItem->song) {
                $price = $cartItem->song->price;
                $songId = $cartItem->song->id;
            } elseif ($cartItem->product_type === 'album' && $cartItem->album) {
                $price = $cartItem->album->price;
                $albumId = $cartItem->album->id;
            }
            
            OrderItem::create([
                'order_id' => $order->id,
                'product_id' => $cartItem->product_id,
                'product_type' => $cartItem->product_type,
                'song_id' => $songId,
                'album_id' => $albumId,
                'quantity' => $cartItem->quantity,
                'price' => $price,
            ]);

            $cartItem->delete();
        }

        return redirect()->route('orders.index')->with('success', 'Order placed successfully.');
    }
```

The audio is currently stored at the Storage/app/public/audio/songs directory.

Here's the result of the downloaded file on my download folder:
[image: downloaded file from the orders]

I tried to put Response $response as argument but still not fruitful. I'm expecting to have an .mp3 file as a result once download.

Comment: You have to use header that is `Content-Type`. You can check out  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418684/946238

Comment: Have you tested if *downloadSong()* is really called?

Comment: I try the approach but still got the same result. Here's how i apply it: $song = Song::find($songId);
        if ($song) {
            $filePath = storage_path('app/public/audio/songs/' . $song->audio_file);

            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                $fileName = $song->title . '.mp3';
                header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
                header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
                readfile($filePath);
                exit;
            }
        }

Comment: Remove the `download` part of your `<a>` because this will result in you downloading all responses (even the redirect response) so you won't be able to tell what actually went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use the header() as mentioned in the comment and successfully resolve the problem. Heres the adjustment to the controller:

```
public function downloadSong($songId)
{
    $song = Song::find($songId);

    if ($song) {
        $filePath = storage_path('app/' . $song->audio_file);

        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            $fileName = $song->title . '.mp3';

            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
            readfile($filePath);

            exit;
        }
    }
    http_response_code(404);
}
```

Comment: In the context of Laravel it is highly recommended you use the appropriate response object.